# format sql table with removing duplicate records

Tags: mysql

this is may be a duplicate question but I was unable to find any solution for this. I have this kind of data table..

```
Name    In_time out_time
John    NULL    9/1/2014 17:00
John    NULL    9/2/2014 11:18
John    NULL    9/2/2014 12:22
John    NULL    9/2/2014 13:22
John    NULL    9/3/2014 13:00
John    NULL    9/3/2014 17:13
John    NULL    9/3/2014 18:13
John    NULL    9/3/2014 19:13
```

my question is how can I remove these duplicate data .rows are unique but date same in out_time column (without time). I need to remove these duplicates permanently only considering the date not the time.the output should be like this.

```
Name    In_time out_time
John    NULL    9/1/2014 17:00
John    NULL    9/2/2014 11:18
John    NULL    9/3/2014 13:00
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the group statement to year,month and day

```
SELECT name,
       in_time,
       min(out_time)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY name,
         DATE_FORMAT(in_time, "%Y-%m-%d");
```

To remove the line in the original table you must do 2 steps
first add a virtual field thar automatic contains the date

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD vdate DATE AS 
  ( DATE_FORMAT(out_time, "%Y-%m-%d") ) PERSISTENT;
```

Then create a new unique Index with IGNORE.

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE your_table ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx2 (name,vdate);
```

This removes directly the duplications

Comment: grouping on the null in time and not the out time?

Comment: Create a second table (your_table2) with the like your_table. **Insert into your_table2 SELECT name,
       in_time,
       min(out_time)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY name,
         DATE_FORMAT(in_time, "%Y-%m-%d");** then in your_table2 are only the result lines

Comment: +1,thanks for the answer but this is a large table which records attendance of employees.so instead of creating a new table I need to remove this data in existing table.

Comment: is it necessary that the first reword from each use not delete, or is it possible that only one per user/day left ?

Comment: I have add my Answer, so you can directly remove the duplications